# checkbox by checkbox by text

Tags: html, checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(chkCat) {
        var dvCat = document.getElementById("dvCat");
            dvCat.style.display = chkCat.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>

<label for="chkCat">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkCat" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" /> Cat 
</label>
<div id="dvCat" style="display: none">

<label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="dvCat" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" /> British shorthair 
</label>
<label> 
    <p id="British shorthair" ></p> 
</label>

<script>
    document.getElementById("dvCat").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("British shorthair").innerHTML = "RM00";
    });
</script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkCat" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" /> Exotic Shorthair 
</label>

<p id="Exotic Shorthair"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("dvCat").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("Exotic Shorthair").innerHTML = "RM00";
    });
</script>
```

1 checkbox. Under this another 2 options checkbox. Select one of the two checkbox the output of both these options came out simultaneously. Try to run this coding. Can you fix my coding?

Comment: You have two checkboxes with the same `id => chkCat`.

Comment: thanks for correcting my codding. I still new in html. If I do not use two checkboxes how I have to call it? I want it like this, when my first checkbox was tick there will came out another option two checkbox, and when click one of the two checkbox there will be another text came out. The problem is both of the text from two checkbox came out simultaneously. What's wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it for now by assigning unique `ID` to checkboxes.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(chkCat) {
        var dvCat = document.getElementById("dvCat");
            dvCat.style.display = chkCat.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>

<label for="chkCat">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkCat" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" /> Cat 
</label>
<div id="dvCat" style="display: none">

<label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="dvSubCat" /> British shorthair 
</label>
<label> 
    <p id="British shorthair" ></p> 
</label>

<script>
    document.getElementById("dvSubCat").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("British shorthair").innerHTML = "RM00";
    });
</script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkSubCat" /> Exotic Shorthair 
</label>

<p id="Exotic Shorthair"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("chkSubCat").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("Exotic Shorthair").innerHTML = "RM00";
    });
</script>
```

P.S: Assigning `id` is not the ultimate solution, if you have more than 1 checkbox falling in same criteria use `class names` instead

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks again!

Comment: If it serves your problem, mark it as an answer please.